# Add points to a polygon based on polygon data

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, point, qgis-processing

Im working with QGIS 3.x, and i have a polygon layer, and each polygon has a value.

i want create a point layer (like random points) but based on each polygon value.

For example: polygon 1 value = 3 then add 3 random points, polygon 2 value = 12, add 12 random points and so on.

Any lead?

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as, from the **Processing Toolbox**:

- Open the **Random Points Inside Polygons** tool
- Select your polygon layer as the input layer
- Use the **Points count** sampling strategy
- Click on the Data defined override button to the right of the count/density field
- Select your value field in the **Field** submenu

The data override uses the field value as a replacement for the tool parameter value.